# Correct way to reference a Session / Global user variable in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a Session variable which is set during the first user login

```
Session["ClientID"]
```

Basically this is used for theming (so the ClientID sets the theme/brand to appear on a website). Looking at the code applying

```
(Guid)Session["ClientID"]
```

All over the place just seems dirty and error prone, what the best design pattern to use to get the variable globally recognized. So I can do

```
this.CurrentClientID
```

or something similar on all MVC Pages. In theory I could overload the `Controller` class with a Custom class providing this ID, but I'm not sure how I would expose this to the View as well.

Any pointers to the best solution would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what you mean globally, but an extension method to the `ControllerBase` class would render it accessible in all your controllers:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static Guid GetCurrentClientID(this ControllerBase controller)
    {
        return (Guid)controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["ClientID"];
    }
}
```

and now inside each controller you can access it:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    Guid id = this.GetCurrentClientID();
    ...
}
```

And if you want it to be even more globally available make it an extension method to the HttpContextBase class:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static Guid GetCurrentClientID(this HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return (Guid)context.Session["ClientID"];
    }
}
```

now everywhere you have access to the HttpContext (which is pretty much everywhere in an ASP.NET application) you simply use the extension method. For example inside a view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("foo link", "foo", new { clientid = Context.GetCurrentClientID() })
```

Comment: Sorry should of clarified, what I mean by globally was "in all controllers and views"

Comment: Sorry for the possibly stupid question, ControllerExtensions - is that a MVC specific function? Or just a arbitrary name that I should make my Controllers extend from.

Comment: Completely arbitrary. You can read about extension methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx Note that they have strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. They are .NET specific.